# Add API present on a local docker container to Kong

Tags: docker, kong, api-gateway

I'm developing a little project with microservices, I want to configure Kong as the API-Gateway for my structure but I'm not able to forward incoming requests from Kong to my services.

For example, I have a docker container running locally on address `172.18.0.15` and port `8006`. I can access the api just fine at `172.18.0.15:8006/compute`, I would like to configure kong in order to be able to make the same call at `localhost:8001/compute`. Am I missing something? Should `api` be present in my url in order for Kong to discover my api? This is the configuration that I've added to Kong, I basically just added all REST methods and set url:port as the upstream-url field.

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "created_at": 1514479841682,
            "http_if_terminated": false,
            "https_only": false,
            "id": "9cf925a5-2c27-4dbc-ae2a-e70fba94ef53",
            "methods": [
                "GET",
                "POST",
                "PUT",
                "DELETE"
            ],
            "name": "compute",
            "preserve_host": false,
            "retries": 5,
            "strip_uri": true,
            "upstream_connect_timeout": 60000,
            "upstream_read_timeout": 60000,
            "upstream_send_timeout": 60000,
            "upstream_url": "http://172.18.0.15:8006"
        }
    ],
    "total": 1
}
```

This is not working for me: when I try to access the API through localhost, the request times out with a `499` error. Any help is highly appreciated.

EDIT: I've tried adding my API by setting the URI field instead. I've inspected using `docker logs kong` and it looks like kong is definetely accessing the correct address, but is timing out for some unknown reason:

```
2017/12/28 17:55:25 [error] 47#0: *103 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: kong, request: "GET /compute?origin=20,20&destination=20,20 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.15:8006/compute?origin=20,20&destination=20,20", host: "localhost:8000"
```

However, if I access the same address using curl it works just fine:

```
# curl http://172.18.0.15:8006/compute?origin=20,20\&destination=20,20
[]
```

I highly doubt anybody else will encounter the same issue but the problem was in my Docker configuration, I forgot to put the api gateway on the same subnet as the services. Fixing this solved my issue.

Comment: Can you make sure kong container can ping your local docker container?

Comment: @Dere0405 Thanks for your comment, it made me realize that the issue was actually in my docker configuration: I had setup services and api gateway on different subnets, this made them unable to ping each other. This is fixed now.

Comment: @EsotericVoid can you please add solution here. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @zulekha my problem was solved by putting my containers on the same subnet. Fixing the IP addresses when launching the containers did the trick for me.

Comment: @EsotericVoid thanks for your comment. I have tried the same, still I am not able to ping my docker container from kong container even if they are on same network.